# Memory bloat after simple get request using Selenium WebDriver for Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, memory, selenium-chromedriver

I was playing with the Selenium WebDriver and encountered the following peculiar problem:

I instantiate the driver without a problem.

```
headless = False #True
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = headless
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",  ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension',  False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', 
{"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36'})
```

Then I use the `driver.get('website-URL')` method to navigate to a URL.

It has been working fine for quite a while now and still does, except for one particular website, which has been blocking me (intermittently) for some time if I tried to use Selenium. Nothing unusual until now.

The **odd thing** I noticed yesterday is that when I try to access this website using Selenium, the `chrome.exe` process started by the WebDriver quickly bloats my memory (usage increments by ~50MB per second). The website just keeps loading (to no avail) until my machine crashes or I kill the process/close the window.

What could be causing this problem? How could I approach debugging this issue?

PS1: I am using Jupyter Lab on Windows 7. Bloating happens in VS Code, too.

PS2: No apparent recurrence of the problem in headless mode, so I assumed it would be something related to the UI(?)

Comment: When your chrome instance is opened and keeps eating RAM, try to open dev tools, switch to [Memory] tab and click [Take snapshot button]. There should be a clue.

Comment: the memory tab in the dev tools does not seem to reflect the problem; it even drops to almost 0 (~1MB heap size) when I visit the site. Nevertheless, the Memory usage shown in Windows Task Manager skyrockets rapidly.

Comment: on the second try it stayed at 12.1MB and did not move while the process of eating up more and more memory.